# What section font is the documentclass scrartcl using and how can you use it in the whole titlepage?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, formatting, titles

I want to have the same koma-font in the `titlepage` as it is used in the `section` or in other words: What section font is the documentclass scrartcl using and how can you use it the whole titlepage?

Minimal working example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge \textbf{AAAA}\par} % this font ...
        {AAAAAA\par}              % ... and this font is different to ...
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\section{AAAAA}                   % ... this font
    AAAAAA
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a KOMA-Script class `\section` uses font elements `disposition` and `section`. By default font element `disposition` results in `\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries` and font element `section` is set to `\Large`.

You could use `\usekomafont{disposition}`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \usekomafont{disposition}% <- added
  \begin{center}
    {\Huge AAAA\par}% <- changed
    {\mdseries AAAAAA\par}% <- changed
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\section{AAAAA}
  AAAAAA
\end{document}
```

or switch to the sans serif font using `\sffamily`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \usekomafont{disposition}% <- added
  \begin{center}
    {\Huge AAAA\par}% <- changed
    {\mdseries AAAAAA\par}% <- changed
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\section{AAAAA}
  AAAAAA
\end{document}
```

Both versions result in

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I found another solution, one could use ```\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont``` inside the ```titlepage``` environment and get the same output or is it a different font?

Comment: @Doesbaddel That’s the default, but many packages change it. In particular, `fontspec` will break it because there is no `cmss/TU/m/n` font. You’re better off selecting `\sffamily in this case.

Comment: @Davislor Ok, thank you for pointing out